# How to prove $9\nmid (3n-7)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How would I go about showing $9\nmid (3n-7)$ where $n \in \Bbb Z$. I haven been asked to show whether $3n \equiv 7mod(9)$ has a solution. I first of all stated that if this were to be true then $9|(3n-7)$, however I can't seem to think of a proof that shows it can't be divided by 9...

Comment: Because $3$ does not divide $3n-7$.

Comment: How would you then prove that... @Robert

Comment: I retract my statement, I see what you mean..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is because we have $$3n\equiv 0,3,6 \mod 9$$ thus $$3n-7\equiv -7,-4,-1 \mod 9$$

Answer (score 3):

If I am stuck with something like this, I sometimes try to write the expression in terms of equations rather than congruences - it sometimes helps me to see things I've missed. Here it works as follows:

Suppose $3n-7=9m$ then $7=3n-9m=3\cdot (n-3m)$, but $3$ is not a divisor of $7$.

Answer (score 2):

If

$9 \mid 3n - 7, \tag 1$

then $\exists k \in \Bbb Z$,

$9k = 3n - 7; \tag 2$

then

$7 = 3n - 9k = 3(n - 3k), \tag 3$

whence

$3 \mid 7. \tag 4$

Impossible . . .

Answer (score 2):

Assume: $9|(3n-7).$

Then :

$3n-7 =9r $, $ r \in \mathbb{Z}$.

$3n -9r=7$,  or

$3(n-3r) =7.$

$\rightarrow:$

$3|7$, which is false.